# Pandasのdataframeでcsvファイルの値を扱う際の"..."による省略が行われてしまう

Tags: python, pandas, csv

以下の写真のように、csvファイルのある値(1枚目)を用いて、関数内で処理を行う際に、長すぎるためか2枚目の写真のように途中から"..."で省略が行われ、それがそのまま値として扱われてしまいます。
3枚目にエラーの内容も載せます。これを解決する方法はあるのでしょうか。
表示に関しては調べたら出てきましたが、自分が悩む問題に関しては関係なさそうでした。
宜しくお願いします。

[image: csvファイルの一部]

[image: csvから読み込んで処理する前に表示したもの]

[image: エラー]

Comment: 実際のコード断片を質問文に追記することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: Pandas のデータフレームとの事ですので、`-4865-...` は文字列として読み込まれているかと思います。例えばこれらの文字列がデータフレームのカラム `b` に格納されているとして、`x['b'] = x['b'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in re.split(r'-|\.{3}', x) if i])` などとすれば `int` のリストに変換することができます。

Comment: コード断片に合わせて実際のcsvファイルの中身も追記するとよいと思います。公開するのに問題があったり、長すぎたりするのであれば、問題が再現する別のcsvファイルを作成しても構いません。